# "get into one's head" in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

> “Don’t let the salesperson pressure you,” Mr. Springer said. “It’s your money after all. **You have to get into your own head and say, ‘I’m here because I want to evaluate this.’** Be pretty critical, because that’s your chance to make a decision.”

Does "get into one's head" mean "form an impression, idea, or plan" here? If so, what idea?

...and say ‘I’m here because I want to evaluate this.’  Say to whom? the salesperson or yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this sentence is essentially two sentences separated by a comma, let's break it down:

> You have to get into your own head

Mr. Springer is referring to the thoughts/mind of that person. He means that the person has to take a break and collect his thoughts (think hard about it).

> I'm here because I want to evaluate this.

This is a continuation of the previous part of the sentence. Mr. Springer wants this person to ask the question to himself.

So in short he says that the person must evaluate the situation before acting. In this case it means:

> Before you spend your money thoughtlessly, think about what you can do with your money, and decide whether the product the salesperson is offering is worth your money or not.

Comment: Note that "get into [someone's] head" is an idiom, but it rarely is used with reference to one's self.